# Update hash value in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

We have table which stores hash data key and value as below

```
sr_category_id_is"=>["194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199"]}
```

We need to update the value using migration.

Sample data:

```
facets: {"status_x_days"=>"", "sr_category_id_is"=>["194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199"]}
```

Comment: Migrate the data into what? Are you concerned about the format of the Hash, when it's serialized to the database, or?

Comment: existing value got changed for some of the Ids so we need to update them, the same needs to be applied in production so we are using migration

Answer (score 1):

you cannot update hash directly in to your db.
You have to assign the existing hash to a variable, do the modifications on that variable, assign it back to the ActiveRecord object and update it.

Example.
Consider User address is a hash

```
user = User.first
address = user.address
address[:City] = "Ahmedabad" #Changed the city from Delhi to Ahmedabad

user.address = address
user.save
```

Comment: Are you sure? The hash is serialised as plain text, right? So I suppose knowing the format for the plain text stored in the database will allow you to change it directly.